# Prove existence of a function $f:\Bbb Z^+ \to \Bbb Z^+$ such that for any $a,b,c$ there exists $n$ such that $f(an+b)=c$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm trying to solve the following exercise from Velleman's "How to Prove it" book:

Prove that there is a function $f:\Bbb Z^+ \to \Bbb Z^+$ such that for all positive integers $a, b$ and $c$ there is some positive integer $n$ such that $f(an+b) = c$.

I have been trying to use the equinumerous theorems between family of functions, but without success. Could anyone give me a hint on how to approach this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: There are only countably many triples of positive integers $(a,b,c)$.  So, try defining values of $f$ one by one, in each step handling one of the triples.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. The main source of confusion in this problem is how to guarantee that $f$ will be a function. For instance, I tried to solve a simplified version of the problem where I have to find $f:Z^+ \to Z^+$ such that for all a, c in $Z^+$ there is $n \in Z^+$ such that $f(an+1) = c$. But I can't avoid having $f(x) = c$ and $f(x) = c'$ with $c \neq c'$

Comment: Ah, but if you're choosing the values one by one, you can choose the values of $n$ each time to avoid repeating any inputs you've already assigned.

Answer (score 0):

Note that triples of the form $(a,b,c)$ for $a,b,c\in\mathbb{N}$ are countable. Thus, there exists a bijection between triples and the natural numbers. Let $S(n):\mathbb{N}\to (a,b,c)\in\mathbb{N}^{3}$ be any such bijection and define

$$\omega(n)=\omega(n-1)[S_1(n-1)+1]S_2(n-1)$$

where $\omega(1)=1$ (where $S_i(n)$ is the $i$th entry of the $n$th triplet). We will now show

$$S_1(n-1)\omega(n-1)+S_2(n-1)<S_1(n)\omega(n)+S_2(n)$$

For the base case, note that

$$S_1(2)\omega(2)+S_2(2)=S_1(2)\bigg[\omega(1)[S_1(1)+1]S_2(1)\bigg]+S_2(2)$$

$$=S_1(2)[S_1(1)+1]S_2(1)+S_2(2)=S_1(2)S_1(1)S_2(1)+S_1(2)S_2(1)+S_2(1)$$

$$>S_1(1)+S_1(2)=S_1(1)\omega(1)+S_2(1)$$

For the inductive step, we have

$$S_1(n)\omega(n)+S_2(n)=S_1(n)\bigg[ \omega(n-1) [S_1(n-1)+1]S_2(n-1)\bigg]+S_2(n)$$

$$=S_1(n) \omega(n-1) S_1(n-1)S_2(n-1)+S_1(n) \omega(n-1)S_2(n-1)+S_2(n)$$

$$> S_1(n-1)\omega(n-1)+S_2(n-1)$$

We conclude that for $i\neq j$

$$S_1(i)\omega(i)+S_2(i)\neq S_1(j)\omega(j)+S_2(j)$$

We now define the function

$$f(m)=\begin{cases} 
      S_3(m)&& m=S_1(n)\omega(n)+S_2(n)\text{ for }n\in\mathbb{N}\\
      0&& \text{otherwise}
   \end{cases}$$